# How to disallow StyleSheet creation in ESLint?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, eslint, react-native-stylesheet

For certain folders I would like to enable `StyleSheet.create()` whereas for other folder I would like to disallow them.

Now I figured out how to override ESLint rules per folder, but how do I disallow `StyleSheet.create()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way that I used is to restrict the import of `StyleSheet`. It is even possible to provide a message with the ESLint warning.

[image]

```
"no-restricted-imports": ["warn", {
  "paths": [
    {
      "name": "react-native",
      "importNames": ["StyleSheet"],
      "message": "Please import StyleSheet only in *.styles.ts files within the components folder."
    }
  ],
}],
```

Then for the override:

```
overrides: [
  {
    files: [
      'app/components/**/*.styles.ts',
    ],
    rules: {
      "no-restricted-imports": ["error", {}]
    }
  }
],
```